# React-select. Two selects based on one source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have data on server and two react-selects.
This is my JSON data:

```
    [{
        "KIA": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Rio"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Sorento"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Stinger"
            }
        ]
    },{
        "VOLKSWAGEN": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Polo"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Golf"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Tiguan"
            },
        ]
    }]
```

This is my first select where I fetched array of cars from the server and put it in state 'cars'. It worked, now I can choose brands.

```
    <Select 
        options={
            cars.map(c => (
                { value: Object.keys(c), label: Object.keys(c) }
            ))
        }
    />
```

So here is what I want for second select:

If choose **KIA** brand in the first select --> I have **'Rio, Sorento, Stringer'** options in the second select.

If choose **VOLKSWAGEN** brand in the first select --> I have **'Polo, Gold, Tiguan'** options in the second select.

Is there a way to bind two selects to one piece of data where options of the second select depend on selected option in the first select? Ugh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This chunk of code is a lot inaccurate, you ll have to format the data  and debug since I didn't run it. It's just to give you a gist regarding the logic :

```
   const dataSet = [{
                "KIA": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Rio"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Sorento"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Stinger"
                    }
                ]
            },{
                "VOLKSWAGEN": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Polo"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Golf"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Tiguan"
                    },
                ]
            }]
```

> Component starts here:

```
      const [ selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand ] = useState()
      const [ selectedModel, setSelectedModel ] = useState()
      const [ brandOptions, setBrandOptions ] = useState(Object.keys(dataSet))
      const [ modelOptions, setModelOptions ] = useState()

// Based on the brand you select, the useEffect should set the relevant options for the models

      useEffect(()=>{
       setModelOptions(brandOptions[selectedBrand])
      },[selectedBrand])


      function handleChangeBrand(brand){
      setSelectedBrand(brand)
      }

      function handleChangeModel(model){
      setSelectedModel(model)
      }

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedBrand}
        onChange={(value) => handleChangeBrand(value)}
        options={brandOptions}
      />
     <Select
        value={selectedModel}
        onChange={(value) => handleChangeModel(value)}
        options={modelOptions}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first select, start by initializing selected_sub_cats to [] in the state

```
<Select 
        options={
            cars.map(c => (
                { value: Object.keys(c), label: Object.keys(c) }
            ))
        }
        onChange={(v)=>this.setState({selected: v, selected_sub_cats: cars.filter(car =>Object.keys(car) === v)})}
    />
```

Then in the second select

```
<Select 
        options={this.state.selected_sub_cars}
        onChange={(v)=>this.setState({selected_sub: v, })}
    />
```